# WP8 ReverseGeocodeQuery Returning Incomplete UK Postcodes

Tags: windows-phone-8, reverse-geocoding

`ReverseGeocodeQuery` is returning an incomplete Postcode e.g. `55.6131/-004.2819` return `"KA17 0"` instead of `"KA17 0BT"`. I have tried a number of locations and the issue is that the final two alphabetic characters are not being included.

Has anyone encountered this issue and if so how did they resolve it?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a34c0944-43a1-434b-9ff4-c3e14570b690/uk-postal-codes-are-truncated?forum=bingmapsservices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that API isn't accurate enough. You could try using this one: 
http://www.uk-postcodes.com/api.php

It gives the result "KA17 0BT" for that latitude/longitude.